# re-zipped docx files don't open in Word

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, docx

I've had success unzipping and examining the interior of a .docx file, but I can't seem to get the re-zipping to work properly. I've tried no compression (command line: zip -0r ...), the archive utility, and a 7zip plugin but none of that works. All of the .docx files I create won't open in the original programs, even when I don't change a single file. Any tips?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It is important that the files that make up the `docx` are not within another folder, i.e. `[Content_Types].xml` must be in the root of the resulting zipped file. [A similar question has been asked on StackOverflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5751687/1030702)

When you open (or extract *to the current directory*) the `zip` file, you should have something similar to the following:

```
./docProps/
./word/
./_rels/
./customXml/
./[Content_Types].xml
```

If you have those files within another directory inside the `zip` or `docx` file, it won't work. Note that I don't get the `customXml` folder on an empty Word document, but the report I originally tested with did have it. You may have some more (or less) directories.

The command to rezip these, issued from the "current directory", is:

```
zip -r preso.pptx *
```

Comment: Thanks. I think the other key was to only edit things with the Terminal. Even after adding `-x .DS_Store`, it would still not work unless I didn't use the Finder to navigate, ever. So I just used textmate and all's well.

Comment: I'm not sure, not having a Mac to test on, but a problem may be caused by Mac and its apps defaulting to the `CR` [newline marker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) and Word expecting a `CR+LF`, even though [the XML specifications say](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-line-ends) to treat them all the same way. I can't say whether Word follows that specification properly or not. There could also be some unexpected encoding changes, or even a hidden file created, once again I can't say anything for sure. It seems you have found a workaround anyway.

Comment: Yeah, I think it was the Finder. I can even open the xml files in textmate or whatever, edit, save, and as long as I do all the zipping/viewing/unzipping in the terminal it's fine. Seems to work now -- the root file thing was the problem. Thanks.